# What is wrapperEl in canvas in FabricJS?

Tags: fabricjs, fabricjs2

https://github.com/salgum1114/react-design-editor/blob/8db73ef3d9846444e25657a5414b417633b1ef0e/src/components/Canvas.js

I have gone through the code on the above link. But I can't seem to understand Line 495 where its written this.canvas.wrapperEl as it is not defined anywhere.

Answer (score 1):

This is [a reference to the wrapper `div`](https://github.com/fabricjs/fabric.js/blob/v2.3.3/src/canvas.class.js#L1372) element that fabric.js wraps around the actual canvas it draws on. This property is intended for internal use, that's why there is no mention of it in the docs.

If you inspect the HTML on a page that uses a fabric.js canvas in it, you'll see something like this:

```html
<div class="canvas-container" style="...">
  <canvas id="c" width="1000" height="800" class="lower-canvas" style="..."></canvas>
  <canvas class="upper-canvas" width="500" height="400" style="..."></canvas>
</div>
```

The `canvas-container` div is your `wrapperEl`.

Comment: Is 'wrapperEl' a keyword which is universal in HTML DOM or just specific to FabricJS?

Comment: @PRS it's specific to fabric.js